# Проблема с OpenGLWidget

Tags: ubuntu, qt5, opengl

Стоит Ubuntu 14.04 64x
Поставил библиотеки Qt5 по инструкции на сайте. Через коммандное окно пытаюсь открыть программу (для которой собственно и требовался Qt5).
Следующей коммандой:
`/usr/local/bin/unico,`
где "Unico" - название программы, которую необходимо открыть.
В ответ получаю следующее:

```
/usr/local/bin/unico: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/bin/unico: undefined symbol: _ZTI13QOpenGLWidget
```

Не могу понять какую библиотеку обновить/даунгрейднуть.

Comment: Выполни команду ldd

Comment: Выполнил, как понять в какой именно проблема, в ручную не переберешь, есть команада для сброса/обновления всех? Буду балгодаре за ответ

Comment: Смотри на какой написанно not found

Comment: @eri ни на одной нет этого, забил на packages.ubuntu.com' QOpenGlWidgets' получил несколько пакетов и установил их через консоль, но ничего

Answer (score 0):

Выполни команду `ldd /usr/local/bin/unico` там будет список библиотек. Напротив потерянной будет написанно not found. Дальше зайди на сайт packages.ubuntu.com и через поиск по содержимому найди пакет, не качай оттуда, а установи через `sudo apt install libqtopengl` или как её там назовут